# C / C++ Error: Pointer variable undefined inside function

Tags: c, function, pointers, error-handling, undefined

From my Java experience it was not hard to get a grip.

A pretty simple function:

```
void update(float * p,float value)
{
    *p = value;
}
```

The compiler is complaining that `identifier p is undefined`.

I thought `*p` would dereference the pointer and store value in it.

Comment: There's no problem with the code you've posted. Please create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) and post that, along with whatever error messages you're seeing.

Comment: What is the exact message from the compiler? any warnings?

Comment: The full error: kalman.c(6): error:  #147-D: declaration is incompatible with "void update(float*, float)" (declared at line 12 of "kalman.h")
kalman.c(6): error:  #141-D: unnamed prototyped parameters not allowed when body is present
kalman.c(8): error:  #29: expected an expression

Comment: That error is unrelated to the pointer assignment. It sounds like either you have another "update" macro in your file or perhaps your compiler doesn't like the way your prototyping. What compiler are you using? Also please provid any additional code in your source/header files

Comment: 'the compiler is complaining that identifier p is undefined' -- I'm really curious why you wrote that when the error message you got doesn't say that or anything like it. Your message refers to line 6 of kalman.c, but you posted fewer than 6 lines. You should post the first 8 (at least) lines of kalman.c and the first 12 lines (at least) of kalman.h ... there's a good chance you're missing a semicolon in the earlier code.

Comment: Yeah there was another kalman.s assembly file and I think the compiler was complaining not being able to distinguish which one to use. Once I renamed my source and header everything was gone. Joys of working with C and assembly in the same project. Thanks everyone for your input though.

Answer (score 5):

OK, so your code looks right, I have to assume the error message is coming from somewhere else. You can try out this "full" version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void update(float *p, float value){
  *p = value;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  
  float p = 3.0;
  update(&p, 5.0);
  printf("%f\n", p);
}
```

Just copy and paste that and respond with any error/warnings you get. If it works fine, then you've miss typed something in your code, if it still gives you issues there's something up with your environment and we'll need more details.